# Complexity of finding M nodes in a graph to maximize the pairwise minimum distance between nodes

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, grassmannian

I want to know the complexity of finding a set of M nodes, $\{U_1,\dots,U_M\}$,  in a given graph $G$, to maximize $d(U_i,U_j)$ over all pairs $i\neq j$, where $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the length of the shortest path between two nodes.

I'm guessing this is NP-hard, but I'm looking for either a reference or a proof (or probably some combination of the two).

The specific graph I'm working with is the Grassmann graph $G_q(n,k)$ (all $k$-dimensional subspaces of the $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_q$). The distance between any two nodes $U$ and $V$ is:

$$d(U,V) = k- \text{dim}(U\cap V)$$

However, the answer doesn't need to be specific to the Grassmann graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're trying to solve is called dispersion. [This paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/037722179090297O) shows that it's NP-complete in general. It can be solved in polynomial time on trees (see [this paper](http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/pdf/10.1287/moor.6.1.50)) but I'm not sure about your specific class of graphs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't able to find anybody referencing that particular problem before.